# Android Catching Error Caused By Official Windows Azure SDK

Tags: java, android, azure, error-handling

I want to catch this error  so that I can handle it myself and not show it to the users. How do I do it???

I'm using the official SDK for Android for Windows Azure.

This error only appears maybe 2-3% of the time. All the other times it connects fine.

Also if the activity in which I try to contact azure  no long exists, then the context no long exists, and it tries to show the message on a non-existent context which will crash the app.

This code is basically straight from the todolist example from windows azure.

Thanks,

Anthony G.

```
        try {
            // Create the Mobile Service Client instance, using the provided
            // Mobile Service URL and key
            mClient = new MobileServiceClient(
                    "XXXXXXX",
                    "YYYYYYYYY", this)
                    .withFilter(new ProgressFilter());

            createTable();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            createAndShowDialog(
                    new Exception(
                            "There was an error creating the Mobile Service. Verify the URL"),
                    "Error");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Exepction caught" + e.toString());
        }
```

And here is the table creation part.

```
try {

        Log.d(TAG, "Create table called and started. ");

        // Get the Mobile Service Table instance to use
        // Don't use the default, because the table on Azure has a different name than the class, instead use this call. 
        mToDoTable = mClient.getTable("MY_TABLE",
                MY_TABLE_SPECIAL_CLASS.class);

        // Create an adapter to bind the items with the view
        mAdapter = new DownloadedMapsListAdapter(this, R.layout.row_list_show_maps_to_download);
        ListView listViewToDo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_data_fromAzure);

        //listViewToDo.setOnItemClickListener(mMessageClickedHandler); 
        listViewToDo.setAdapter(mAdapter);          

        // Load the items from the Mobile Service
        refreshItemsFromTable();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Exepction caught" + e.toString());
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I'm an idoit. In the refreshItemsFromTable() there is the actual 'execute' statement was being called (I didn't post it in my question). Execute is when it actually contacts Azure. The function checks to see if exception is null rather than using a try-catch. So what was being displayed was the CreateAndShowDialog(exception, string).

Maybe this will help someone else.

```
/**
 * Refresh the list with the items in the Mobile Service Table
 */
private void refreshItemsFromTable() {

    // Get the items that weren't marked as completed and add them in the
    // adapter

    Log.d(TAG, "refreshItemsFromTable");
    mToDoTable.execute(new TableQueryCallback<MapObjects_FromAzure>() {

        public void onCompleted(List<MapObjects_FromAzure> result, int count,
                Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
            if (exception == null) {

                Log.d(TAG,
                        "refreshItemsFromTable on complete, with no exception thrown so far. ");

                mAdapter.clear();

                for (MapObjects_FromAzure item : result) {
                    mAdapter.add(item);

                }

            } else {
                createAndShowDialog(exception,
                        "Error" + exception.toString());
            }
        }
    });
```